# Why can't I send or receive files using Google Talk?

Tags: file-transfer, google-talk

I have an install of Windows 7 64-bit. Actually I have 3, and the one I'm talking about is the only one with this issue. It seems that I can send IMs and be involved in VOIP calls, but nothing will convince this one system to send or receive files.

Any thoughts about what might be wrong with this particular system?

Comment: kneejerk reaction is firewall issue

Comment: I Kinda see that, but Google help pages suggest ports are shared between voice and file transfer. Since I can do VOIP, I feel I should be ok here

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't be more help.  I don't use googletalk so idk, but I posted it as a comment so you could rule it out or have an aha moment.

Comment: What happens when you try, or is the option simply disabled?

Comment: The "Send Files" button is missing and I cannot drop the files on the conversation in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... Interesting turn of events.

It seems that my 'broken' instance of Gtalk was running version 1.0.0.105 and all others were running 1.0.0.104

I uninstalled 1.0.0.105 and then went to the official google-talk site only to discover that the official version is 104. Strange.

I downloaded it, installed, logged in and everything is now working.

Comment: May be version 1.0.0.105 is the [Google Talk Labs Edition](http://www.google.com/talk/labsedition/index.html)? From the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/talk/labsedition/faq.html), "Google Talk, Labs Edition is an experimental release that brings some of the great features of the Google Talk Gadget to the desktop. **Some features like voice calling and file transfer from the Google Talk client did not make it into this version.** If you need to use voice calling or file transfer, you can download the original Google Talk client...". But you say you could use VOIP?